# LyX --- QED symbol same as last line of the proof (instead of line below)

Tags: lyx, proof-package

I understand that usually for LaTeX we do \qedhere to force the QED symbol to appear where you want it.

How do I change the Proof environment in LyX to get LyX to do the same thing?

Right now if I have alignat environment as the last bit of my proof, the QED square appears one line below where I would like it to be.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know it's simple only with the `ntheorem` package.

Comment: if you are using `amsthm`. insert `\qedhere` before `\end{equation*}` or `\]`.

Comment: if you could provide a small compilable example, you'd likely get more extensive answers.  not knowing what document class you're using or which packages puts potential answerers at a distinct disadvantage, requiring them to use telepathy or a crystal ball, neither of which has been perfected yet.

Comment: As Barbara said, some more information would be useful. At the very least, which theorem-module are you using? Better, create a small sample document and add that to your question.

Comment: @KennyLJ I think my answer is correct. Do you have any feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any `amsmath` environment such as `alignat`, you can add `\qedhere` at the end of the last cell and wrap it inside `\tag*`, as follows:

[image: \qedhere inside \tag*]

For repeated usage, I recommend defining a macro as follows:

[image: macro with \qedhere inside \tag*]

I have been using this trick for years, it always worked for me.